# XCode Instruments: Leaks NSMallocBlock no stack trace in extended detail

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I am using XCode 4.6.3. I using the Leaks template in Instruments. It detected a leak and the object is NSMallocBlock. When I click on the leak object, the extended detail pane says "No stack trace available for this block." How do I know where is the leak in my code? Attached is the screenshot of Instruments. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Leaks screenshot]

**Edit:** 
Matteo Gobbi gave a suggestion. I tried to click on the arrow on that item and then on one of the item on the list but there is still nothing in the extended detail pane. Attached is the screenshot of what I have tried.

[image: Leaks screenshot 2]

Comment: Did you ever get a solution?